# Installshield, After installing app, user is prompted with installer

Tags: c++, installation, installshield

I'm currently using Install Shield 2011 to build an installer for one our products, which in of it's self basically installs several smaller exes, that work as part of a larger system, and we've noticed that some installer builds, will prompt the user to install one of the applications again, even though the user just installed the app. Any suggestions on what could be causing this, or what settings to look for? Thanks.

If I click cancel on the prompt to install the, program does start up. If I let the installer run again, the prompt does go away. If i do an uninstall of the app before installing the new version, it goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like auto repair, part of the resilience of Windows Installer. Look in the event log for an indication of what component is triggering repair, and follow the trail to the problem in your installer.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the event viewer, the only odd message i get when clicking on the offending exe is: Application 'D:\d3\Dsply.exe' (pid 4296) cannot be restarted - Application SID does not match Conductor SID..

Answer (score 1):

what kind of prompt to user, from the installer or from the OS? If is the PCA, you can refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756937.aspx

Comment: This is really a comment on another post, rather than an answer.

Comment: It prompts me withe the MSI installer dialog.